# Using Knockout type with TypeScript and RequireJs for ES5

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, requirejs, ecmascript-5

I am learning TypeScript and struggle with the knockout type right now.

Right now I import the dependencies and then use them in my `showPdf.ts` file like this:

```
import $ = require("jquery");
import ko = require("knockout");
import pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf");

export class PdfViewModel {
    pdfUrl: any;

    constructor(initUrl: string) {
        this.pdfUrl = ko.observable(initUrl);
    }

    var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
    loadingTask.promise.then((pdf: any) => {
        pdf.getPage(1).then((page: any) => {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

### 1. KnockoutObservable

Now I would like to set the type of `pdfUrl` to `KnockoutObservable<string>`. Without changing anything else, I now get a transpile error:

```
Error TS2403: Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'ko' must be of type 'typeof import("C:/Users/BluE/Source/Repos/ShowPdfTest/node_modules/knockout/build/types/knockout")', but here has type 'KnockoutStatic'. (1060, 13)
```

I got this fixed by changing the knockout import to this:

```
/// <reference path="../TypeScript/@types/knockout/index.d.ts" />
import $ = require("jquery");
import pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf
```

Now I have read, that using the reference like that is actually bad practice. So what would be the correct way of doing this?

### 2. PdfJS

Visual Studio also highlights 2 issues, those compile and work fine though.

```
Import 'pdfjsLib' is never used
Symbol 'pdfjsLib' cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module
```

If I remove the import, the other line won't transpile anymore.

```
Error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'pdfjsLib'.
```

Am I doing something wrong here? If so, what is the correct way of doing it?

### Additional config info:

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js/",
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "name": "showpdf.test",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.30",
    "@types/knockout": "3.4.66",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "requirejs": "2.3.6",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "knockout": "3.5.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.0.943"
  }
}
```

The effective html parts of my `*.cshtml`: (I am using ASP.Net Core 2.2, in case it is relevant.)

```
<script src="~/lib/requirejs/dist/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "/",
        paths: {
            "jquery": "lib/jquery/dist/jquery-3.4.1",
            "knockout": "lib/knockout/dist/knockout-3.5.0",
            "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf": "lib/pdfjs/dist/build/pdf",
            'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker': "lib/pdfjs/dist/build/pdf.worker",
            "showpdf-test": "js/showpdf"
        },
        waitSeconds: 15
    });
    require(
        ["knockout", "showpdf-test"],
        function (ko, showpdf) {
            var viewModel = new showpdf.PdfViewModel("");
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
    );
</script>
```

[image: File structure in my solution]

I just noticed I am using the Nuget package knockoutjs. I doubt, that I actually need it. Are there any known issues having this nuget package though?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure it is going to work but try using `import * as ko from 'knockout` instead and removing `lib` and `typeRoots`. If that doesn't work, try using this tsconfig file and renaming the file to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot"
    ]
}
```